# Use method from class in form

Tags: c#, winforms

I have class in my project named `Visibility.cs` and I wanna use method named `HospodaVisible()` in `Form1` but it doesnt work. It isn't showing usercontrol.

here is code of class and `form1`:

```
public static class Visibility
{
    static Form1 f = new Form1();
    public static void HospodaVisible()
    {
        f.hospoda1.Visible = true;
        f.arena1.Visible = false;
        f.podzemi1.Visible = false;
    }
    public static void ArenaVisible()
    {
        f.hospoda1.Visible = false;
        f.arena1.Visible = true;
        f.podzemi1.Visible = false;
    }
    public static void PodzemiVisible()
    {
        f.hospoda1.Visible = false;
        f.arena1.Visible = false;
        f.podzemi1.Visible = true;
    }
}
    
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        hospoda1.Visible = false;
        arena1.Visible = false;
        podzemi1.Visible = false;
    }
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Visibility.HospodaVisible();
    }
}
```

Comment: How does your `Main` method look like? Does it show a form?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See if this works for you:

```cs
    public static class Visibility
    {
        public static void HospodaVisible(Form1 f)
        {
            f.hospoda1.Visible = true;
            f.arena1.Visible = false;
            f.podzemi1.Visible = false;
        }
    }
    
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Visibility.HospodaVisible(this); // passes a reference to the "current" form, i.e. Form1 itself
        }
    }
```

`this` is a reference to the current instance of a class inside the class, in other words it's `self`.

In the code above you passes a reference to the active, current form to a static helper method which accepts a reference to a form (doesn't instantiates one) and makes the necessary changes to it. Basically, it says: "hey helper, do something with *this* form".

Comment: It probably will, but will you explain what the OPs problem was and why your proposal fixes that?